# How can a Windows user's username be automatically determined upon Page_Load?

Tags: c#, windows, iis, active-directory

Can a Windows user's username be automatically determined without requiring the user to login with their username and password for a Web Application? This user would have of course logged into Windows with this same Active Directory username.

What I am seeing so far is that if I have the Web Application setup in IIS connecting as the *Application user (pass-through authentication)* using an Application Pool with a **NetworkService** identity and **NetworkService** having *Read & execute*, *List folder contents*, and *Read* access, then one of three things happen:

1. With Anonymous Authentication enabled and Forms Authentication enabled, the webpage returns the IIS's host name as Environment.UserName, and therefore cannot obtain the user's username automatically.
2. With Anonymous Authentication enabled, ASP.NET Impersonation enabled, and Forms Authentication enabled, the webpage returns **IUSR** as Environment.UserName, and therefore cannot obtain the user's username automatically.
3. With Windows Authentication enabled, a pop-up window asks for the user's username and password.

I am viewing Environment.UserName on Page_Load:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set username on interface
        txtUsername.Text = Environment.UserName;
    }
```

And if I was asking the user for credentials, I would use:

```
//Determine if user entered the correct username and password
bool AuthenticatedViaAD = DomainContext.ValidateCredentials(loginModule.UserName, loginModule.Password);
```

What I am hoping to use, without asking the user for their username, is:

```
//Get current user
UserPrincipal currentUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(DomainContext, Environment.UserName);
```

*Page.User.Identity.Name* populates appropriate after the user enters their username and password with Windows Authentication enabled:

```
txtPageUser.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: You should stick to `Page.User` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.user?view=netframework-4.7.2 as `Environment.UserName` does not apply to ASP.NET in almost all cases.

Comment: Thank you @LexLi. I used Page.User.Identity.Name, but it only populates after entering the user's username and password (only populated for option 3 above). Is there a way for Page.User to populate without the user entering their username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to the browser security policy (If entering your windows credentials does work)

IE, and most other browsers will not submit windows auth to non-trusted, or intranet web sites as this is an obvious security risk.

Try adding the site to your trusted sites list, and see if that resolves your issue.

Comment: Thank you Tim. I will try adding the website to Trusted Sites.

Comment: Yes, both IE and Chrome will only send Windows credentials to sites in the Trusted Sites list in Inter Options. I believe Firefox has its own list.

Comment: Also use the server's FQDN in the URL, not IP address.  And check the server(s) and client(s) time are synchronized.  Not sure if this is only for Kerberos, or will generally prevent pass through of Windows Integrated credential, so I thought I would mention it.

Comment: @Tim, the website has been added, and it appears that I am receiving the same results. I believe it may be a security safeguard preventing the functionality I was hoping to see.